# How to debug root cause for active handles increasing in nextjs project

Tags: node.js, next.js

in one of our nextjs project that has very dynamic map (real estate project), we see huge number of active handles in nextjs project. If we run `pm2 show frontend` it shows the active handles. It keep increasing and quickly it crosses 2000+ active handles.

Any idea how we can debug it? Thank you.